# can't pass php array to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Not able to pass PHP encoded `array` to `js`.

**index.php**

```
echo '<script src="script.js"></script>';
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5);
echo json_encode($a); 
?>
```

**script.js:**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'index.php',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (Data) {
        alert("Success!" + Data);
    },
    error: function (Data) {
        alert("Wrong");
    }
});
```

I always got message - "Wrong".

Comment: remove this line `echo '<script src="script.js"></script>';` from your code

Comment: I have removed it... and I have got it same alert - wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have not pass html tags in your json value generated from php

```
echo '<script src="script.js"></script>';
```

simply delete the code above. also, you have to parse your JSON string after your function is succssed, :

```
function (data) { 
   JSON.parse(data).forEach(function (x) { 
       alert(x); 
   }); 
}
```

Comment: I have deleted code above.

I have tried your code and maybe it is correct, but array is not printed(echo)  in .php file... :(

Comment: I have inserted code... still got alert - Wrong...Here it is:

$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
 
    success: function (data) { 
   JSON.parse(data).forEach(function (x) { 
       alert(x); 
   });
 },
    error: function (data) {    
 alert("Wrong");
 },
});

Comment: I don't see any problem., maybe other configurations are missed.

Comment: Give me urls if problem is still breathing

Answer (score 0):

use post method i think It work

```
method: 'POST',
```